# How can I select a range of pages in VBA for Word?

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word, range

I'm creating a macro for a friend at work. At our job, the first time a term is mentioned, we have to use the full name. Every time the term is mentioned after that, we use an acronym. I made the following macro in Microsoft word:

```
Sub AcronymResolver()
'Creates the Acronym and Term strings
Dim Acronym As String
Dim Term As String

'Prompts the user to assign a value to Term using an InputBox

Term = InputBox("Please enter the Term you wanted modified.", "Term selector")

'Prompts the user to assign a value to Acronym using an InputBox

Acronym = InputBox("Please enter the acronym you want to replace it with.", "Acronym Selector")


'Replaces every instance of the Term with the Acronym
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = Term
.Replacement.Text = Acronym
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False
.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll

' Uncomment this code if you ALWAYS want to replace the first
' occurrence in the document, otherwise the first occurrence
' from the START of the selection will be replaced
Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
End With



'Replaces the first instance of the Acronym with the term
With Selection.Find
.ClearFormatting
.Replacement.ClearFormatting
.Text = Acronym
.Replacement.Text = Term
.Forward = True
.Wrap = wdFindContinue
.Format = False
.MatchCase = False
.MatchWholeWord = False
.MatchWildcards = False
.MatchSoundsLike = False
.MatchAllWordForms = False

.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne


End With

End Sub
```

Now she has asked that I modify the code so that she can select a range of pages, and perform the macro only on those.

I'm not sure where to begin on this; I had some idea of trying to use an If statement to modify only the pages in a certain range, using a counter, but I am also having trouble selecting just certain pages as I think my code is set to modify the whole doc. I am new to VBA, so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the first replace operation to just the selected range by using

```
.Wrap = wdFindStop
```

instead of wdFindContinue.

Personally, I would be more concerned with the risk that the search term happens to be part of another word, or (for the second replace) that the acronym happens to occur within a word. It would be safer to use

```
.MatchWholeWord = True
```

But that would mean that you have to run the macro twice if you want to search for the plural of a word as well as the singular.